# STM32 SPI MISO stay high

Tags: embedded, stm32, spi

I'm trying to make basic SPI communication between 2 stm32 devices. HAL is used for that purpose. Idea is to exchange data between 2 MCU every 1 sec. So I create timer which purpose is to generate interrupt every 1 sec (timer is used to set flag for start SPI communication). MCU are configurated to work in full duplex mode (1 master and 1 slave).

My problem is next: 2 MCU communicate as expected when SPI is configurated to work on lower bandwidth (when prescaler is 256 or 128). As speed increases data collect more and more garbage on MOSI line. Basically MISO line don't works as expected. MISO line stay high (look picture) when it should be low.

Master code:

```
#define SPI_SLAVE_SYNBYTE     (0xAC)
#define SPI_MASTER_SYNBYTE    (0x53)

bool flagSpi1 = false;
uint8_t rxSpi[10] = {0};
uint8_t txSpi[10] = "Milan";

void Synch(void)
{
    uint8_t txAck = SPI_MASTER_SYNBYTE;
    uint8_t rxAck = 0;
    do
    {
        if(HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_DMA(&hspi3, (uint8_t *)&txAck, (uint8_t *)&rxAck, 1) != HAL_OK)
        {
            Error_Handler();
        }
        while(HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi3) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY){}
    }while(rxAck != SPI_SLAVE_SYNBYTE);
}
void Receive_Spi_Master(void)
{
    if(HAL_SPI_Receive_DMA(&hspi3, rxSpi, 10) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    while(HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi3) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY){}
}
void Transmit_Spi_Master(void)
{
    if(HAL_SPI_Transmit_DMA(&hspi3, txSpi, 10) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    while(HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi3) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY){}
}
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
    if(htim->Instance == TIM5)
    {
        flagSpi1 = true;
    }
}
main(void)
{
    Init_Part();      

    while(1)
    {
        if(flagSpi1)
        {
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
            Synch();
            Receive_Spi_Master();
            Synch();
            Transmit_Spi_Master();
            Synch();
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_SET);
            Send_Data_To_Terminal_Via_Uart(rxSpi);
            HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOE, GPIO_PIN_15);
            flagSpi1 = false;
        }
   }
```

}

Slave code:

```
#define SPI_SLAVE_SYNBYTE     (0xAC)
#define SPI_MASTER_SYNBYTE    (0x53)

uint8_t txSpi[10] = "Test";
uint8_t rxSpi[10];

void Synch(void)
{
    uint8_t txAck = SPI_SLAVE_SYNBYTE;
    uint8_t rxAck = 0;

    do
    {
        if(HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_DMA(&hspi1, (uint8_t *)&txAck, (uint8_t *)&rxAck, 1) != HAL_OK)
        {
            Error_Handler();
        }
        while(HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi1) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY){}

    }while(rxAck != SPI_MASTER_SYNBYTE);
}

void Transmit_Spi_Slave(void)
{
    if(HAL_SPI_Transmit_DMA(&hspi1, txSpi, 10) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    while(HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi1) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY){}
}

void Receive_Spi_Slave(void)
{
    if(HAL_SPI_Receive_DMA(&hspi1, rxSpi, 10) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    while(HAL_SPI_GetState(&hspi1) != HAL_SPI_STATE_READY){}
}

main(void)
{
    Init_Part();

    while (1)
    {
        if(!HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_4))
        {
            Synch();
            Transmit_Spi_Slave();
            Synch();
            Receive_Spi_Slave();
            Synch();
            HAL_Delay(3);
        }
    }
}
```

When code "works" (it works but I think that MISO line is wrong, this picture represent low speed SPI - prescaler is 256)
[image]

Comment: Who did tell you that it should be low?

Comment: Noone, diagrams which I found on internet doesn't have MISO line high in idle

Comment: it sends something random when idle - it is normal behaviour (at least for STM32 uCs). if you want to make sure zeroes are clocked out,  you need to feed data register with zeroes.

Comment: If /CS is not asserted the slave device will tri-state its SO line allowing other devices to assert the line when selected. If no device is asserting the MISO, then the quiescent state is determined by whether the MI is pulled high or low, and either is fine - without a clock running, it is a "don't care".  It is not a software question, it is a https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ question.  The MISO may be pulled-high externally or by the internal GPIO configuration.

Comment: @P__J__ : There is nothing "random" about it unless there is no pull-up/pull-down, and noting is being _"sent"_ while there is no clock and no /CS

Comment: Your problem is that you are getting garbage data at high speed, but your question is about the MISO state when idle.  How is that relate to your problem?  The MISO idle state is irrelevant.   Rather then using a logic analyser, you should scope the lines to check the slew-rate.  The rise time may not be fast enough to reach the logic threshold before the state changes at high speed.  Stating the prescaler value is unhelpful - what is the resultant SPI clock frequency in Hz?  What is the slave device or specifically what is its maximum speed?  Still not a software question however.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Clifford he asks why he is getting non zero values when slave does not actively send data.

Comment: @Clifford your comment does not make too much sense. If CS is deselected and there is no clock - no data is send/received.

Comment: @P__J__ That is what I said.  You said "_it sends something random when idle_", it is not "sending", ant the idle state is not "random".

Comment: @P__J__ : I know what he is asking, but he refers to data errors at high- speed.  Why then is he asking about the idle state at low speed?  It seems, he thinks that the fact that the a MISO state is not as he expected is somehow related to the errors.  It's an X-Y problem.  We can tell him why the MISO is high; that won't solve his data errors. It is most likely a signal integrity issue, or he has simply exceeded the spec. of the part.  Whatever is pulling the MISO high however, may also be affecting the signal integrity of course.

Answer (score 0):

When Idle, MISO doesn't matter, nothing should be reading it. Ignore that.

When you are getting garbage, what does your screen look like?
Are all your pins configured for high speed?
Can both devices communicate at high speed?
Can you show us something basic configured for low speed then the same output for high speed?